# How does @Value work in SpEL?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-el

I have a class A with a date field annotated with @Value to take as default value the current date.

When I create a bean in an XML file, this field appears to be initialized with the current date, as expected.

When I create a new object with new A() in main of a test class, the field is null.

My question is how does @Value work. In the documentation, it said it gives a default value to a field, but does it work only for beans? How is it processed?

Comment: Yes, only Spring managed beans will be injected with a value for the `@Value` annotated field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the bean *using the XML file*, Spring creates the bean and applies the injection of configured fields, via XML configuration or decorated by annotations e.g. `@Autowired`, `@Value`, etc...

When creating the bean using `new YourClass`, then you're manually creating an instance of the class, thus not being handled by Spring.

If you want Spring to handle new beans created on demand i.e. using `new` keyword, you can refer to [Spring injecting or autowiring datasource bean to class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17819752/1065197), point 3 and the explanation at the bottom using `@Configurable`.