# setter method not working in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I have tried to initialize setter method from context file.But it isn't working as expected.

//setter method

```
public class Service {

    private long Id=0;

    public long getId() {
        return Id;
    }
    public void setId(long Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

}
```

//calling method

```
public class test {

    //...source code
    Service sercvi = new Service();
    System.out.println("******************ID"+sercvi.getId());
    .................................. 

}
```

Context.xml

```
    ..........................................
    ..........................................
    <bean id="Service"  class="com.test.Service.Service" > 
      <property name="Id" value="100"/> 
    </bean>
   ...........................................
   ..........................................
```

Here goes loading context file in web.xml file
web.xml

```
...............................
    ....................
    <!-- Spring load context.xml - -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/Context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

If i run the application it always return 0 value for id but i have initalized 100 in context.xml.
Why that value is not retrieved ?
How to initlialize setter method value from context file?
Also how to retrieve those value?

How to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Service` instance is being created manually. `Spring` will only fire the injections when your bean is handled by the Spring context.

> How to resolve this error?

**Do not** initialize your beans manually, recover them using Spring context or by Spring injection.

You may inject the bean inside another bean:

```
@Component
public class FooComponent {
    @Autowired
    Service service;
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(service.getId()); //prints the value injected by Spring
    }
}
```

Or recover it directly from the Spring context

```
@Component
public class BarComponent {
    @Autowired
    BeanFactory beanFactory;
    void bar() {
        Service service = (Service)beanFactory.get("service");
        System.out.println(service.getId()); //prints the value injected by Spring
    }
}
```

There's another option that let you create the beans manually and getting all the Spring *power* within them by using `@Configurable` annotation as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17819752/1065197).

---

In case you want to test your Spring beans, use [JUnit + Spring Test](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/testing.html), but this is more used for integration testing rather than unit testing.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(location={"classpath:location/of/your/spring.xml"})
public class MySpringTest {
    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @Test
    public void fooTest() {
        System.out.println(service.getId());
        Assert.assertEquals(100, service.getId());
    }
}
```