# How to access list from another method?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

i am new to java. I was trying to create a login module.

I have this in a package.. Now I want to call this login() method from jsp file how can I do that using (or not using) userController object.

```
package com.lagan.controller;
import java.util.List;

import com.lagan.dao.userDao;
import com.lagan.dto.loginDto;
import com.lagan.dto.userDto;

public class userController {
    public List<loginDto> login() {
        userDao dao=new userDao();
        return dao.login();
    }   
}
```

Comment: ok....... but in loginVerify.jsp if I had to call create() [in UserController.java], i could have done uC.create() ... Similarly what can i do to call list<loginDto> login(){} ? That is my problem. coz uC.login() is not valid..

Answer (score 0):

In your JSP page you need to have an object of UserController. Typically in JSPs, you need to have a  tag to create that object. 
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jsp/use-bean-in-jsp-page/

But in Spring based application, in which all objects are managed by the container, you need to provide a mechanism to fetch the appropriate object from the container.
Take a look at this thread:
[retrieve Bean programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775888/retrieve-bean-programmatically)

Comment: I certainly didn't understand what it meant..  My question is.. There is another method in userController called create(userDto user). I can access it easily by creating userController object uC (uC.create(userDto)) from jsp. But in this case it is a list type. So how can i access it? uC.login() didn't work.

Comment: It's somehow strange, nothing should be wrong in your JSP page; perhaps the problem is related to the controller and Java code. Can you debug the Java code by your IDE and check whether it returns the list successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Get the user controller method

```
<%
UserController userController = new UserController();
List<LoginDto> list = userController.login();
%>
```